# How to cite a course overview note?

Tags: citations

I am summarizing a course overview note which includes some useful information about digital marketing. The thing is, there's a endnote that clearly says that the course was prepared by professor X and professor Y. However, another endnote says that this 'course overview note' (the note itself) was prepared by professor Z. There are no citations in the note except for further suggested readings and a few explicit ones.

So when I am summarizing the ideas, should I cite them as: (Professor Z 2013) or always refer to (Professor X & Professor Y 2013)? Note that I, obviously, don't have access to the original course material itself.

Edit: Author of the note says: 'while maintaining many concepts and cases, this note provides an alternative structure and view of the set of frameworks to their original course'. However, it isn't clear where his ideas start and end, and where their original ideas do so.

Comment: Anyone to help?

Answer (score 1):

Since the course overview note is credited to Professor Z, that's who I'd cite. But you could include all the authors in the citation itself if you liked, for example:

- Professor Z (2013) Title of the Course Notes. Distributed as part of the course materials for DEPT304 Course Title in Fall 2013, a course developed by Professors X and Y at the University of Hishouse. Available online at http://example.org/.

Of course, it would be ideal if you could find a more widely available source for this information; it might be hard for your readers to track down this one course overview note, but if you could find the same information in a textbook or a review article and cite *that* instead, I think that would make their job a lot easier!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already stated in the intro. that the course was prepared by X & Y and the course note itself was developed by Z. The note is a Harvard Business Paper so I think it's widely available, yet for a paid access. Anyway, its availability doesn't really matter since the instructor gave the paper for me only to prepare it for his class discussion.